# Android since Kitkat doesn't deliver updates to inner adapter views

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, android-4.4-kitkat, notifydatasetchanged

We have a ListView with BaseAdapter and each row contains horizontal ListView (just AdapterView).
Before KitKat (Android 4.4) expanding some row inside ListView lead it for trigerring getView() for whole ListView and it lead to calling getView() for all the inner adapter items of this row. But starting KitKat it doesn't work like this anymore - inner adapter just doesn't receive any messages that will lead it to update its views.

Is it a part of KitKat optimizations? Should we now force Android to update inner adapter views manually?

UPDATE:
The same problem (not trigerring getView() on inner adapter views) was found on Nexus 7 with Android 4.3

Comment: I don't think that nested `AdapterView` has ever been officially supported, so I doubt that it is a use case that Google worries about much. Plus, there is no horizontal `ListView` in Android, and so the problem may lie with whatever implementation of that it is that you are using.

Comment: As I wrote horizontal ListView is just AdapterView in our case. And nested AdapterView always received updates in previous Android releases

Answer (score 1):

We finished finally by adding the following block inside getView() of ListView's BaseAdapter:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
  parent.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      (<inner adapter>).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  });
}
```